# How to use slf4j logger to print logs to a file for debug and other levels

Tags: java, maven, logging, slf4j

I know this question has been asked before and from the other responses I am reading I pieced together a bunch of information but I am still failing to achieve what I wanted.

My goal is to have my maven/java project to print logs at info, debug, trace, etc level to a new file each day. Ideally I would like jan21.info.log, jan22.info.log, jan21.debug.log, jan22.debug.log.... etc you get the idea but I can't even get my program to print to a file. I have pasted my pom.xml, java class and log4j.properties file below. Slf4j is a requirement btw.  As you can tell this is very very basic but I can't get this to work for some reason. Highly appreciate any help here. Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:
the program is able to create a text file in the root folder and write to it fine.  I added the write code as well to App.java below.

pom.xml

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>my-app</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.5</version>
 </dependency>
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
 
  </dependencies>
  
   <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.mycompany.app.App</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
     </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

src/main/resources >> log4j.properties

```
# Root logger option 
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, file 
# File appender 
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender 
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p - %m%n 
log4j.appender.file.File=/Users/ajanis/DR/GS/tmp/my-app/myoutput.log 
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=100KB
```

src/main/java >> App.java

```
package com.mycompany.app;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class App 
{
   private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(App.class);

   public static void main (String [] arg) throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException
   {
      System.out.println("\n\nBegin\n");
      log.info("hello info");
      log.debug("debug");

      PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("blah.txt", "UTF-8");
      writer.println("The first line");
      writer.println("The second line");
      writer.close();

      System.out.println("\nEnd");
   }

}
```

Comment: Check the write access

Comment: Write access is fine. I was able to create blah.txt in the root directory. I updated the question to add that note. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all - it looks like you want to use log4j for logging but you don't have proper [binding](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html#swapping) i.e. `slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar`. Take care that you need to remove existing `slf4j-simple` dependency!

Second to your naming problem: I would recommend you to use logback as binding since it is quite flexible in configuration. See eg. [time based rolling](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#TimeBasedRollingPolicy).

Comment: Good call! Replacing slf4-simple with slf4j-log4j12 worked. Thank you.

Comment: do you mean example of configuration file? one is in the link I have provided. or do you search for something particular?